# Get URL from onclick attribute with JSOUP in java

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am new with Jsoup and I am trying to get the URL from onclick attribute which calls a function called `ga` and which has five parameters , so it looks like this `ga('send', 'event', 'tunein', 'playjp', 'http://link that i want to get');` , I want to grab the `http` url.

I tried with `attr("onclick")` option but it doesn't function at all, do you know if there is a chance to get this somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are on the right node ?

node.attr("onclick") should work

Can you post the link of the page you are trying to **scrape** , and how you reach the node ?

```
public void jsoupParse() throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.internet-radio.com/station/dougeasyhits/").get();
        Element image = doc.select("div.jp-controls").select("i").get(0); //get the first image (play button)
        String onclick = image.attr("onclick");
        System.out.print(onclick);

    }
```

output :

```
ga('send', 'event', 'tunein', 'playjp', 'http://airspectrum.cdnstream1.com:8114/1648_128.m3u');
```

now all you need to do is manipulate the string with 'split' method to extract the url :

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.internet-radio.com/station/dougeasyhits/").get();
    Element image = doc.select("div.jp-controls").select("i").get(0); //get the first image (play button)
    String onclick = image.attr("onclick");
    String[] parts = onclick.split("'"); //i split the string in an array of strings using [ ' ] as separator
    String url = parts[9]; //the url is contained in the 10th element of the array
    System.out.println(onclick);
    System.out.print(url);
```

output

```
    ga('send', 'event', 'tunein', 'playjp', 'http://airspectrum.cdnstream1.com:8114/1648_128.m3u');
http://airspectrum.cdnstream1.com:8114/1648_128.m3u
```

this is how the "onclick" attribute got split in case you are confused :

```
parts[0] : "ga("
parts[1] : "send"
parts[2] : ", "
parts[3] : "event"
parts[4] : ", "
parts[5] : "tunein"
parts[6] : ", "
parts[7] : "playjp"
parts[8] : ", "
parts[9] : "http://airspectrum.cdnstream1.com:8114/1648_128.m3u"
parts[10] : ");"
```

Comment: here you have `https://www.internet-radio.com/station/dougeasyhits/` inspect the play button

Comment: Instead of `.select("div.jp-controls").select("i")` use `.select("div.jp-controls > i")`. Also use `.selectFirst(...)` instead of `.select(...).get(0)`. Looks nicer.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have managed to get this output, but my problem is how to use split method to extract url, thanks a lot for your response